# IL Generate Proxy to User Define Func<TInput, TReturn>

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, code-generation

I'm trying to dynamically generate an assembly to call a func created by a user.

```
private MethodBuilder DefineGetMethod<TInput, TReturn>(
     TypeBuilder tb, MethodDescriptor methodInfo, Func<TInput, TReturn> dynamicMethod)
{
    //Define the function
    var dynamicMethodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod(methodInfo.MethodName,
              MethodAttributes.Public,
              methodInfo.ReturnType, methodInfo.InputParameters.Select(x => x.Type).ToArray());

    //Define the labels for the method inputs
    for(var i = 0; i < methodInfo.InputParameters.Length; i++ )
    {
        // Position 0 is the return value, 1 is the 1st param, 2 is 2nd, etc.
        var position = 1 + i;
        var inputParam = methodInfo.InputParameters[i];
        dynamicMethodBuilder.DefineParameter(position, ParameterAttributes.None, inputParam.Name);
    }

    var ilGenerator = dynamicMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    //Loads arg1
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

    //Not sure how to pass the arg1 to the method body to return
    var ilMethodBody = dynamicMethod.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

    //Generates return
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

}
```

**EDIT**
I Decompiled existing code, to call the the method in a similar way to the decompiled existing code but I still cannot get it to work

```
// Argument 1 of dynamic method is argument array.
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, method.Method);
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

How can I pass the loaded argument to the `ilMethodBody` and return?

Comment: how about `ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, dynamicMethod.Method)`?

Comment: Ooo. That looks promising,  will that pass the parameters?  I'll test it later tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT - Johnny 5**

It turns out you can just make a jump statement to the existing method info:

```
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Jmp, method.Method);
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

First of all, you have to make sure `TReturn` equals to `methodInfo.ReturnType` and `TInput` equals to first of `methodInfo.InputParameters`.

If `dynamicMethod` is a static method delegate, it's will be easy like:

```cs
private MethodBuilder DefineGetMethod<TInput, TReturn>(TypeBuilder tb, MethodDescriptor methodInfo, Func<TInput, TReturn> dynamicMethod)
{
    var dynamicMethodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod(methodInfo.MethodName,
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                methodInfo.ReturnType, methodInfo.InputParameters.Select(x => x.Type).ToArray());

    var ilGenerator = dynamicMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, dynamicMethod.Method);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return dynamicMethodBuilder;
}
```

But if `dynamicMethod` may be an instance method(lambda with be a instance method), it's will be hardly. call the instance method need push the instance onto stack first, but `Emit` only allow push constant value like int, string.

I can only think of one way, declare a field to store `dynamicMethod`, set field value after build type by reflect:

```cs
private Type DefineGetMethod<TInput, TReturn>(TypeBuilder tb, MethodDescriptor methodInfo, Func<TInput, TReturn> dynamicMethod)
{
    var fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_func", dynamicMethod.GetType(), FieldAttributes.Private | FieldAttributes.Static);

    var dynamicMethodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod(methodInfo.MethodName,
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                methodInfo.ReturnType, methodInfo.InputParameters.Select(x => x.Type).ToArray());

    var ilGenerator = dynamicMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    // load static field _func onto stack
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, fieldBuilder);
    // load arg1 onto stack
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    // call _func.Invoke(..)
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, dynamicMethod.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"));
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var type = tb.CreateType();
    var field = type.GetField("_func", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    // store dynamicMethod into static field _func
    field.SetValue(null, dynamicMethod);
    return type;
}
```

**EDIT**

test code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OnlyStaticFunc();
        StaticField();
    }

    static void OnlyStaticFunc()
    {
        Func<string, int> func = int.Parse;

        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("StaticFuncTest");
        var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name);
        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Abc", TypeAttributes.Public);
        var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Execute", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, typeof(int), new[] { typeof(string) });

        var il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, func.Method);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var value = ((dynamic)abc).Execute("123");
        Console.WriteLine($"only static func: {value}");
    }

    static void StaticField()
    {
        Func<string, int> func = s => int.Parse(s);

        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("StaticFieldTest");
        var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name);
        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Abc", TypeAttributes.Public);
        var fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_func", func.GetType(), FieldAttributes.Private | FieldAttributes.Static);
        var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Execute", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, typeof(int), new[] { typeof(string) });

        var il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, fieldBuilder);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, func.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        var field = type.GetField("_func", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        field.SetValue(null, func);
        var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var value = ((dynamic)abc).Execute("456");
        Console.WriteLine($"static field: {value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this complete after I get a chance to test it tonight's

Comment: this isn't exactly what I wanted but it works so I can't complain :)

Comment: I found out how to do it, I edited your answer so now you have 3 different ways to accomplish it

Comment: :D new knowledge, got it